# Type check in Zope

Tags: python, zope

I want to check if an variabel has type list

```
if isinstance(filter, type([])) != True:
    filer = [filter]
```

when i try this zope can't find type.

And that i cant use:

```
isinstance(filter, list)
```

couse Zope means "list" is an Variabel

Comment: Are you using `filter` and `list` as variable names elsewhere in your code? These are python built-ins and you don't want to overwrite them. If you are, that's a really bad idea, and this is exactly the sort of problem you run in to.

Comment: yes filter is my variable but i dont use list

Comment: If you haven't overwritten the `list` builtin then your code `isinstance(filter, list)` should work fine. Can you edit in the error you're seeing exactly?

Comment: i'm sry. Somewhere i use list
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'list' referenced before assignment

Comment: No problem. I've added an answer. Just ask if you need any more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing python code it's important not to overwrite the builtin variables.

It looks like you used `list` as a variable name, preventing `isinstance` from working as expected. It is also worth noting that `filter` is a builtin as well, and you should probably find another name for whatever you're storing in `filter`.

Comment: Now i used an external Script in the Extension Folder. Its too much code to recode it.